# How do you join mastodon.social?

Tags: mastodon

I was trying to follow a user on `mastodon.social` but I when I try to look for that server on the site, it's not there.

Comment: What Mastodon instance are you using? Maybe `mastodon.social` is not federated with it. How are you looking for the user or the server?

Comment: It says on the side: `The original server operated by the Mastodon gGmbH non-profit`

Comment: I'm completely new to Mastodon.

Comment: I guess it doesn't matter which one you join as long as it doesn't block another instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the larger Mastodon instances occasionally close to new registrations so they don't become overwhelmed. (Remember, it's not funded by advertising, so new users don't necessarily mean new revenue.) But you can follow a user on `mastodon.social` from any other Mastodon instance which federates with `mastodon.social` (which is most of them). Or, indeed, from many non-Mastodon servers too. (Mastodon isn't the only server which implements the ActivityPub protocol.)

Comment: I just found a different one and the federated access seemed to do the trick from there.